# Generate Key of 64 bit in DES encryption Algorithm c#

Tags: c#

I searched about this question and found solution but i found that key sometimes generated in 64,63, 62 or 61 i don't know why can any one help me 
and thanks for your help

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] buff = new byte[8];

rng.GetBytes(buff);

StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(64);

for (int counter = 0; counter < buff.Length; counter++)
{
    hexString.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", buff[counter]));
}

string Key = hex2binary(hexString.ToString());
```

Comment: What does the `hex2binary` does?

Comment: note that `new StringBuilder(64)` is overlong... `new StringBuilder(buff.Length * 2)` is enough, because a byte in hex is 2 characters.

Comment: You should populate your array with random bytes. Here is something related to it: http://www.dotnetperls.com/random-byte-array

Comment: @Andy He is already doing it correctly. `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`

Comment: @xanatos this to convert to binary i want to store the 64 bit one string my algorithm based on that

Comment: @ManarYousry buff is already binary enough. `hexString.ToString()` is printer-friendly/user-friendly.

Comment: @xanotos hexString.ToString() print hexa value not binary i tried it so i used convert to binary function

Comment: i got it when it convert hexa to binary a problem happened 
say if hexa= 123
binary should be 000100100011
function hex2binary neglicted el 000 from the left of the binary 
many thanks for your help